# need to dig in narrow rocky land

Tags: gardening

We have very rocky land and need to dig about 3 feet (by 2 feet) next to the garage/home wall.  Is there a special equipment that will do the job without damaging the home's walls?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's called a pick and a shovel. Should take an hour or three. I own a backhoe - I don't try to get close to my foundation walls with it - that's inviting disaster. P&S is also inexpensive and can get anywhere, unlike equipment.

If you mean "solid rock" the answer is a bit different, clarify if that's the case. For rocky dirt (or any dirt) loosen with pick (and/or digging bar), remove with shovel.

[image: pick/mattock]
[image: digging bar]
[image: shovel]